# MapStruct spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, mapstruct

Does anyone know why mapStruct doesn't allow DTO class to have less elements than the ENTITY class.

for example I have this entity :

```java
public class Provider {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="provider")
    private Set<Product> products;

}
```

and the dto :

```java
public class ProviderDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

the Dto doesn't contain the attribute 'products'
which give me this error:
[image: tap to see image if the error]

ps: when i add List to the DTO, everything works fine. But i want that my DTO class contains only the attributs that I want, not the same ones as in the Entity class.

Comment: Add error messages as text not as image

Comment: And while you are at it, please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. For example, a git repository with the application code and an integration test that shows this behaviour would be very helpful.

Comment: If you are using maven, please try to run `mvn clean package` to force a re-generation of the MapStruct-generated code, for gradle it should be `gradle clean build`. MapStruct should not try to map what isn't there. This can happen when we modify the entities / DTOs, but MapStruct does not regenerate the mapper implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your source and target objects are not identical, you need to define the difference in your mapper class's mapping method.

1. If source and target object has different names of properties you need to define which property name of source will be mapped to which property name of the target.
2. If target does not have a property but the source has, you need to specify ignore for that property on the mapping method.

   @Mapping(target = "products", ignore = true)

Comment: thanks! that was the solutions.

Comment: for anyone that's facing the same problem please check this link for more information on the solution : https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-ignore-unmapped-properties

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message it seems that you have the DTO objects, the entity objects and the mapper most likely each in their own modules. But when adding them to the end product you are using versions that aren't matching with the functionality needed.

The generated mapper that is being used expects the List object in the DTO class. But the supplied DTO information doesn't have this. Which means that the mapper needs to be updated so that it knows that the DTO class doesn't have this field.

In code:

```
// DTO module version 2
class DTO {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  // removed: private List<String> list1;
  // leaving out setters/getters
}

// Entity module version 1
class Entity {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private List<String> list1;
  // leaving out setters/getters
}

// Mapper module version 1 with dependencies on:
//   DTO module version 1
//   Entity module version 1
interface Mapper {
  DTO EntitytoDto(Entity source);
}

@Generated
class MapperImpl {
  DTO EntitytoDto(Entity source) {
    // mapping code for field1, field2 and list1.
  }
}
```

End result of the above code is a `NoSuchMethodError` when it tried to map `list1`.

What you want is:

```
// Mapper module version 2 with dependencies on:
//   DTO module version 2
//   Entity module version 1
interface Mapper {
  DTO EntitytoDto(Entity source);
}

@Generated
class MapperImpl {
  DTO EntitytoDto(Entity source) {
    // mapping code for field1 and field2.
  }
}
```

Hope this helps with solving the issue.